# Vue keyboard events not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, dom-events, vue-router

Vue isn't firing any keyboard events, it reacts to click events but attempts to watch and fire `keypress`, `keyup`, `keydown`, `change`, `input`, `focus`, or `blur` all don't do anything. I did a jQuery test to watch for the same events and they were all fired accordingly so what am I missing with Vue?

Here's my template so far that watches for keyboard events

```
...
<input type="text" placeholder="email" :value="email" v-on:change="updateEmail"/>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" :value="password" v-on:change="updatePassword"/>
...
```

and I've tried replacing the above with many variations of different events as noted further above, the `change` event was my latest attempt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you reproduce it on jsfiddle.net? `v-on:input` should work usually.

Comment: I wrote a pen on codepen using Vue, VueRouter, and Vuex [link here](http://codepen.io/wiseguy12851/pen/VaqprX) but it works as expected leading me to believe the problem is elsewhere. On my end I'm using Webpack to build so my guesses are its either webpack, the fact that its a sub-component causing it to not build right, jade interpreter that may be messing up the v-on, or something else.

Comment: I found the issue and its fixed, thanks for your quick help

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem and it was a combination of a few things, the core issue was an html typo further above the listed code here `<srong>...</strong>` that should have triggered an error but didn't and therefore threw off the event system somehow.

It didn't trigger an error because of the second issue which was due to an abandoned plugin `gzip` where I forgot to delete the gzip files and therefore the server was serving them (older gzipped files) rather than the newly built files.

I abandoned the plugin because I thought it was interfering with the 3rd and 4th issue where a jquery plugin wasn't working right. The problem to those was I didn't take into account windows path matching which uses a `\` so `[\\\/]` was needed to match both Windows and unix paths and therefore wasn't setting up the lib code properly, that in combination with installing the plugin in a seperate chunk causing it not to be installed in all chunks made up the root cause.

So all is fixed now, thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-model`:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="email" v-model="email">
```

This will automatically sync the input with the value of email

The shortcut for the `change` event would also be `@change="updateEmail"`

Comment: Well I'm also using vuex data store, is there a way to pickup model updates so I can call the necessary function on the vuex store?

Comment: See this example from the docs, it is exactly what you're trying to do: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html

Comment: Try using `<input>` instead of `<input/>`.... Do you have any console errors? Please show vuex actions also

Comment: Tried removing the end slashes, no console errors, here is my vuex actions `actions: {
            updateEmail(store, e)
            {
                console.log("updateEmail", arguments);
                func("auth", "setEmail")(store, e.target.value);
            },

            updatePassword(store, e)
            {
                console.log("updatePassword", arguments);
                func("auth", "setPassword")(store, e.target.value);
            }
        },`

Comment: console.log is never called either

Comment: I found the issue and its fixed, thanks for your quick help